# Paypal randomly marking some orders as complete

Tags: paypal, order-status

A client of mine on Magento 1.9.0.0 is experiencing an issue with Paypal randomly marking some orders as complete in the back end and invoices are blank so have to be prepared manually.

We've just moved the client to a new server but that shouldn't have any impact.

Any ideas anyone?

Comment: Paypal have admitted the issue is at their end, and are trying to fix it as a matter of “high importance”